# Ubuntu 16.10 no sound whatsoever

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

Audio used to work on my Ubuntu system (not as it should have, but it worked). Something happened recently, I have no idea what, but now I've completely lost sound.

I've basically tried everything that you can find looking at Google results for this problem. Here are some commands and their outputs:

Trying to open `alsamixer`:

```
bertalanp99@watermelon:~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

Running *lspci*:

```
bertalanp99@watermelon:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

`inxi` output:

```
bertalanp99@watermelon:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: watermelon Kernel: 4.10.0-33-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 6.3.0)
           Desktop: Gnome 3.24.2 (Gtk 3.22.11-0ubuntu3) Distro: Ubuntu 17.04
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: Gigabyte model: H87M-D3H v: x.x UEFI: American Megatrends v: F11 date: 08/18/2015
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-4570 (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 25540
           clock speeds: max: 3600 MHz 1: 3535 MHz 2: 3600 MHz 3: 3600 MHz 4: 3600 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 770/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.66 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 NVIDIA GK104 HDMI Audio Controller bus-ID: 01:00.1
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 4000.8GB (1.8% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10EZRX size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD10EZRX size: 1000.2GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: WDC_WD20EZRX size: 2000.4GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 98G used: 15G (16%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /home size: 98G used: 47G (50%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 8.59GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C gpu: 0.0:37C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 254 Uptime: 36 min Memory: 2805.4/7930.9MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 6.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.71) inxi: 2.3.8
```

I would be very grateful for any kind of help!

**EDIT: Upon request, more outputs:**

Running `lspci-k` gives:

```
bertalanp99@watermelon:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd H87 Express LPC Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GK104 HDMI Audio Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
```

Executing `aplay -l` yields:

```
bertalanp99@watermelon:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

Contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2

# My additions
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Comment: I would suggest you try a Live CD and see if sound works with that, in order to eliminate a hardware problem which has developed. If it works, then compare the related settings and installed packages between the Live CD and your installed system.

Comment: @AFH I can certainly do that, but as I said, audio was working fine for a long time. It worked yesterday. But nevertheless I will check on a live session. But what should I compare exactly?

Comment: I booted with a Ubuntu Live CD. I got strange results. My setup is that I have two front speakers and a subwoofer that are connected  to the back panel of the PC and I have headphones which are connected to the front. In the live session, when I tried Test Sound, I could only hear sound from the right channel of the headphones. No sound from the speakers...

But hardware should be fine, as in Windows (I'm dual booting), sound works without complications.

Comment: I didn't know you were dual-booting, so the Windows installation confirmed the hardware. I've never had a problem with sound on Ubuntu (apart from the performance with Bluetooth speakers), but I'm on 16.04. Your results are certainly puzzling. Maybe plugging in the headphones (which I would expect to mute the speakers) sets signals which are handled differently by the two systems. But I'm at a loss to know what to suggest next, apart from unplugging the headphones.

Comment: @AFH Puzzling indeed... The problem is that I don't think anything works now. Not even the headphones out the speakers alone (ie. when the other is unplugged). But Ubuntu doesn't even recognize my soundcard any more!

Comment: I have never fully got to the bottom of Ubuntu's device handling: there's nothing equivalent to Device Manager in Windows. I would try and find the Ubuntu device driver and reinstall it, once saving settings on the removal, and again with complete removal if this doesn't work. If all else fails the ultimate resort is to reinstall over the top of the current installation (after backing everything up, of course) in order to go through device detection again.

Comment: @AFH I have already removed and reinstalled tons of stuff related to audio, with no success. I don't even think reinstalling Ubuntu would work, since the audio didn't work in the live session either...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using PulseAudio? I find that it tends to work better than Alsa.

Comment: No reason for anything. I don't know how sound works in Ubuntu... I didn't know they are substitutes for one another. I have both ALSA and PulseAudio installed... I just want sound back, doesn't matter how

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete in your home directory the files `.asoundrc` file and `/etc/asound.conf` (if you have them) and reinstall `alsa-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Neither of the two files you mentioned exist in my system. About reinstalling `alsa-utils`: Been there, done that. Actually, I have done it at least thrice. No success whatsoever :(

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -k` or `aplay -l`. I notice you have two audio cards, so try `alsamixer -c 1` or 2 or even 0, as I don't know which one is right. Another: Sometimes removing the user from group audio and adding it back helps.Add also to your post the contents of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (see [link](https://justus.berlin/2015/05/no-sound-on-ubuntu-linux-cannot-open-mixer-no-such-file-or-directory-solved/))..

Comment: I added the outputs of those commands and the contents of the configuration file to the question. I have already tried running `alsamixer -c n` with various numbers for `n`. I always get: `invalid card index: n` where `n` is the number I enter. I have already added myself to the audio group and removed myself as well. Nothing.

Comment: Do you get the same if you run `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` followed by `sudo aplay -l`?

Comment: `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` gives me `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.0-33-generic`

Comment: Do you have a `snd-hda-intel` line in the file `/etc/modules` ? If not, append it and reboot. Ensure also that you have all alsa packages installed.

Comment: I didn't have anything in `/etc/modules`, except comments. I added the line `snd-hda-intel` as you asked. Rebooted, nothing has changed. `sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel` still gives me an error. I think I have all alsa packages installed, but how can I check? What packages do I need exactly?

Comment: Your problem is pretty resistant. None of the solutions I know have worked, and I'm astounded that with two audio devices your audio is still totally disabled. If you are sure that you have all the modules and drivers and it still doesn't work, my only advice would be to reinstall Ubuntu. But as the live CD doesn't work either then I'm not sure that it would help. I hope it's not hardware, but that's as far that I can take it.

Comment: Quite so. I am not really sure about that, but I am not really familiar with how drivers work in Ubuntu yet. And yes, the live session didn't have sound either. Funny thing is, in Windows, I do have sound (I'm dual booting). That's what's peculiar to me. Anyways, thank you for your effort.

Comment: The live cd might not have the right 3rd-party drivers, so there is still hope for a reinstall. If it works in Windows, at least this is not hardware.

Comment: I might have to resort to that reinstallation in the end then... Final question, is there a way to back up most of my configured stuff (.bashrc, .profile, theming, etc) so I don't have to start from scratch? It took quite a while to get comfortable in Ubuntu

Comment: Reinstallation can keep `/home` even if it's not on a separate partition (see [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/630973)). System configs need to be saved & restored manually. Because of the risk of duplicating the problem by restoring these, go slow and step-by-step. The simplest backup is to image the disk or partition and have a boot cd for restoring. If you have Windows, AOMEI Backupper Standard may be useful.

Comment: Can't I first check if it would work by installing the 3rd party tempararily in my live session? Or would that require a reboot (thus I'd lose my installed packages, since it's just a live, temporary session)

Comment: You can try installing drivers and alsa packages in the live cd and trying modprobe, but you won't be able to reboot. If you can arrange for a small but sufficient empty disk partition, you might try the installation there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user you use may access the group audio?

Try:

sudo usermod -a -G audio {username}

Then logout and login again.